# Is threading possible for sprites- LibGdx

Tags: multithreading, libgdx

I want to implement an event in a SCENE2D game.

There are three sprites and they are moving/rotating at a time.I want to make the movements in a synchronized way so that it will act like a single object.
(Like parts of a single machine).

To achieve this,which method I can follow?
I thought of using threads first and I read this article in GitHub.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Threading

But I am confused after reading it, whether using threading on graphic object like sprite is OK.If OK,how can I frame the threads?If not OK,which way I can follow to achieve the synchronized movement of sprites?

Comment: In each call to your game's `render()`, you update all your object positions, then draw them, and then they appear on the screen. All the motion will appear to happen simultaneously. Do not use multithreading for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use threading, but it is relatively hard to implement correctly and will most likely leave you with hard to track concurrency problems.

You can just use the render method to update the sprite movement. If your game isn't too heavy it will just run at 60 fps and the delta time will ussualy be around 1/60th of a second. When it gets higher though you need to decide if you want to skip updates or make them go faster for instance (untested pseudo code):

```
float rotationFactor = 0.1f;

public void render(float delta)
{
    sprite1.rotate(delta * rotationFactor);
    sprite2.rotate(delta * rotationFactor);
    sprite3.rotate(delta * rotationFactor);
    ...
}
```

Or if you want to prevent big rotation steps when the game goes slower for a bit

```
public void render(float delta)
{
    sprite1.rotate(rotationFactor/60);
    sprite2.rotate(rotationFactor/60);
    sprite3.rotate(rotationFactor/60);
    ...
}
```

if you really do want to use threading I would recommend using a timer and calling `Gdx.app.postRunnable()` when it times out. This way updates will still be executed on the UI thread.

Comment: How this rotationFactor will work here?Actually I don't want to use threads at all.I just want to avoid the delay while setting position after rotation.It happens one by one.That makes it feel these sprites are seperate part of the object.

Comment: it is just the rotation speed (0.1 deg/rad per second, depending on what libgdx uses). the actual screen update should happen after this rotation step.